# A new fiddle for dba.se

Tags: discussion

Update Jan 2020:

## Please note, the place for reporting db<>fiddle bugs and feature requests is [now on this TopAnswers post](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=30#question) pending a future move to a GitHub issue tracker!.

---

SQLFiddle has been an essential tool and a great complement to dba.se for a very long time, but it has gone downhill a bit in the last year or two.

I have also wondered for some time what a 'fiddle' designed specifically with dba.se and markdown in mind might look like, and over the last few days I've put together [a prototype](https://dbfiddle.uk) of how I think it should be.

Please have a play with the site and let me know here if you have suggestions for improvements or design changes.

The current list of supported databases is:

- Db2 Developer-C 11.1 (with lots of thanks to [@mustaccio](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio))
- Firebird 3.0
- MariaDB 10.2, 10.3 and 10.4
- MySQL 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0
- Oracle 11.2 and 18
- Postgres 8.4, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 10, 11 and 12
- SQL Server 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2017 Linux and 2019 Linux RC1
- SQLite 3.8, 3.16 and 3.27 (but 3.16 is currently offline for [security reasons](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2018-20346))

Here's an example (the image links to the fiddle):

- [image]

I've edited some of my answers (e.g. [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87365/1396)) to use db<>fiddle.

As of Apr 2018 the site uses ssl by default — there are some benefits even for a site like db<>fiddle and [it's free now](https://letsencrypt.org/2014/11/18/announcing-lets-encrypt.html) so why not?

As of Apr 2019 you can now [hide batches selectively](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f997165482043f33d498a26e1457f5e7&hide=31).

Comment: +1, +10, +1000000000000000000

Comment: ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

Comment: +2 also. It would be a welcome addition. As wishes are cheap: having several versions (i.e.: PostgreSQL 9.4, 9.5, 9.6...) of the same DB would be a plus. Sometimes you don't know when your problem is just version specific... and you'd better upgrate quickly.

Comment: @joanolo "As wishes are cheap" not at all, thanks for the suggestion. I've added 9.5 and 9.4, and will add others at some point!

Comment: As sqlfiddle is an established site, and you seem to have already [invested time and effort in to it](http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html) according to the about page, couldn't SE just adopt it and _make sql fiddle great again_, by pushing some resources towards it's development?

Comment: @Tanner when I saw the writing on the wall a couple of years ago, I asked that question, but although help was offered, it wasn't the sort that Jake needed.

Comment: @JackDouglas fair enough, just thought I'd ask... you know, reinventing the wheel n all. good luck, would be interested to see how it develops.

Comment: @Tanner thanks, feel free to post feature requests here if you have ideas.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what are SQLfiddle/DBFiddle? I followed the links but they didn't have any explanatory text. I also couldn't find any reference on DBA.SE about them.

Comment: @BradC Try this one: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=a07be800358e332f41b6aab5d7507c59 the point is that you can make a reproducible test case demonstrating a question or problem, and then others can tinker with it (try changing the sql in the link in this comment)

Comment: @BradC also, there is a bit of documentation on the home page for each RDBMS: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next

Comment: @JackDouglas: Others *who don't have the target dbms installed* can tinker. That's the big deal for me. I'd usually rather see the SQL in the question, myself. There's no reason people can't include SQL in the question *and* in a fiddle, but that's not as common as I would like it to be.

Comment: @Mike we can't force that (except by editing posts), but yes, all the SQL should go in the Q&A as well as the fiddle. I've tried to make this as easy as possible with the 'markdown' link next to the 'run' button — I only added this yesterday so you may not have seen it?

Comment: @JackDouglas: I haven't looked at dbfiddle.uk yet. Just tossing in my two cents during a one-minute lull at work. :-)

Comment: @JackDouglas: Looks good at first glance. I'll start using it.

Comment: @Mike great, please let us know bugs and/or feature requests in an answer here :)

Comment: @JackDouglas Is this just for dba.se or is it alright to spread to stackoverflow?

Comment: @SqlZim yes, that's absolutely fine — it seems fairly stable now. Please let me know here if you find bugs though…

Comment: The site has evolved. By now, in all modesty, I'd like to say ***it's absolutely marvellous***.

Comment: Coming from you @Erwin, that mean a lot, thanks!

Comment: @JackDouglas Great website :) I have a small problem with [nullable column](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=5c1dd2ec44751ef268bb1bc94a7118c8) SQL Server vNext. It works with previous versions, but with vNext I have to explicitly mark column as nullable to make it work.

Comment: @lad2025 I missed your comment for some reason but I can't repro this now on 2016 or with any of the SQL Server versions currently supported (eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=5c1dd2ec44751ef268bb1bc94a7118c8). It may have been a vNext bug or somethingthat has since been fixed.

Comment: @JackDouglas Hi, I got silly question: [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1b992e2b99a43c0973a6d6865fa2b036) vs [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56494/3/1) Is there any particular reason why I got only one column? Is there any possibility that you will support PostgreSQL 11/Oracle 12c?

Comment: @lad2025 thanks for spotting that bug, [now fixed](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1b992e2b99a43c0973a6d6865fa2b036). Regarding db support, pg11 will be added soon, but Oracle 12c probably never as there is no XE version. 18c XE is thought to be coming up (possibly in July) and if that materializes I will add it.

Comment: @JackDouglas Thanks a lot for such quick response. I will wait for Oracle 18c (love that platform for many new features :) It would be also nice if you consider adding support for Vertica/Terradata.

Comment: @lad2025 no problem :) please consider whether you could ask/answer more questions here on dba.se btw. I think there is a community version of Vertica, but not sure about Teradata, do you know whether there is?

Comment: @JackDouglas Thanks for invitation. I will contribute more at dba.se (will be new experience for me, but I see there are many of my DB heroes) . As for Terradata I believe that https://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express-for-vmware-player would be helpful.

Comment: Looks great. not sure why it needs a link to a religious organisation ?

Comment: @Mitch both dbfiddle and my church are intended to help people, and both are the product of a lot of effort. I don't push either on anyone — and I hope to have the same respect shown to me by those who believe differently.

Comment: Great tool. However, many people posting questions seems unaware that there is such help available. Not sure that it would actually help, but would it be possible to add a link in the "How to Ask" box? Also, any plans to extend it with support for Db2?

Comment: @Lennart I'm not sure if SE would want to promote my tool over any of the others available — you could ask a separate question on meta to find out? Regarding Db2 I'd love to add it to the list and I've tried a couple of times to install it on Linux but failed. It may be easiest to use a Windows back-end instead but I haven't got round to trying that.

Comment: @JackDouglas, I never experienced problems with installing Db2 myself, but I have heard plenty of people that had the same situation. Don't know if that's an option, but there is a Developer-C container available that should address some of the issues with the install: https://store.docker.com/images/db2-developer-c-edition

Comment: @lennart db<>fiddle doesn't use docker or containers — it has full-fat VMs for the backends. I was trying to install it headless on Debian which isn't as using a supported distro, but apparently should work.

Comment: @mustaccio if you could give me a (tested) step by step guide to getting DB2 working on Debian Stretch that would be fantastic. If that isn't easy, second best would be another flavour of Linux (it wouldn't matter much which). I have found guides I just haven't managed successfully put any of them into practice yet! Thanks very much for the offer regardless :)

Comment: @JackDouglas I suggest moving the Db2 conversation to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90950/db2-for-dbfiddle

Comment: Great work. In MySQL 8.0 fiddles, the performance schema is enabled, but grants are not given to see performance schema data. Is this intentional, and if so what is the motivation behind it ? (Disclosure, I am the author of pfs)

Comment: Hi @Marc, there wasn't a conscious reason — just erring on the side of safety where I wasn't sure. From what I can tell from the docs, there is no security risk in enabling `select` on `performance_schema.*`, which I've done: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=189b630c14c27a347e1874c4e9f29fde. Do you need `update` as well, or anything else?

Comment: Hi @JackDouglas, thanks for the quick fix. Read only (SELECT) access should be preferable I think, so that fiddle from user 1 does not interfere with user 2. At least now people have a change to see the performance schema stats collected, and write fiddle that uses the data.

Comment: Postgres 11 seems to be offline. No results ...

Comment: Sorry about that @Erwin, it's back now. Do you know of a way of restricting a session/user/schema to a particular limit?

Comment: I might. What kind of limit?

Comment: @Erwin I'd especially like to impose a disk quota

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to achieve that. Don't think there is a way in standard Postgres.

Comment: @Erwin how about a background job that polls the database and kills any session corresponding to a schema that has grown too large, does that sound sane?

Comment: Sounds tedious, error prone and expensive. Not sure what's best. Maybe a `TABLESPACE` with limited size per user and according schema, search_path, permissions ... ?

Comment: Jack, regarding donations to help pay for dbfiddle.uk, what is the organization that pays the maintenance fees?  I'm trying to see if a donation qualifies as a [charitable contribution](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/charitable-organizations/charitable-contribution-deductions) under U.S tax codes.

Comment: @John it's a UK limited company, not a charity — the overheads of setting up as a non-profit would outweigh any donations I'm likely to get I'm afraid! Thanks for considering it though :)

Comment: Any chance of getting sqlite 3.28 added to the list of supported databases? 3.8 is ancient.

Comment: @Shawn we were waiting for Debian 10 [to release](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2019/06/msg00003.html), which is packaged with 3.27. Shame 3.16 doesn't seem to have been patched in Debian yet, I don't know why.

Comment: @Shawn 3.27 is now [available](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27)

Answer (score 15):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thank you for this. I have been using [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler) for this, but it doesn't work properly for Oracle.

I don't like the tiny input field to start with. I would prefer it to be presented as a much wider (and higher) text field so that it's immediately clear that you can input more then just a few characters.

It also doesn't auto-expand for subsequent statements (using Firefox on Windows 10). After pressing the `+` the input field stays at the initial size. You *can* input larger statements but you can't see them properly.

I know parsing SQL is hard, but having to click the `+` button for each new statement is a bit cumbersome.

> Also, if anyone wants to talk me through installing SQL Server 2016 on Debian without a GUI, I'm all ears

What about: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-docker

Comment: "It also doesn't auto-expand for subsequent statements" thanks, fixed! I've tinkered with the [home page](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2) a bit which may make it a bit clearer (please tell me if you think it doesn't). I don't want to parse the SQL at all if possible — I've toyed with the option of allowing a separator or magic character to be specified as a delimiter — maybe with a 'paste script' button.

Comment: I think you can install on Debian (perhaps 'testing', that's fine) — I did find half a HOWTO but it wasn't detailed enough. That link seems to be about Docker in particular which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: @JackDouglas: there is an installation procedure for Ubuntu: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu

Comment: That's much more like it :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35541418#35541418

Comment: "having to click the + button for each new statement is a bit cumbersome" you no longer have to do this if you are pasting in a whole script into an empty field — DBFiddle will split on ';' (or GO for SQL Server).

Comment: NB: Bug in the last output value: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b2c5dc069e4355eeb0327b732a7a52c7 (query to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324597/361842)

Comment: @JohnLBevan please can you explain the bug, it isn't obvious to me (preferably in a new answer here rather than a comment on this answer)?

Comment: "having to click the + button for each new statement is a bit cumbersome" — I've come round to thinking you are right so a blank batch is now auto-added if you edit the last batch. Please let me know if you find this better? I'm also aware that at some point I broke the 'auto-splitting' feature, but I've had second thoughts about that too. Now if you paste test that includes multiple separators the page will just prompt you to click the 'split' button by making it visible).

Comment: @JackDouglas Apologies; I can't see any issue now; not sure if the bug's been fixed, or if it was user error on my part.  Please disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Just as a suggestion:

For me syntax coloring would be appreciated.

And some short-key to execute instead of click on RUN button.

And I don't know if it is a vNext feature, but dates fields are shown using this long format:

```
 Jan  1 2017 12:00:00:000AM
```

Comment: Thank you, great suggestions. No idea about the dates except that it's probably British defaults?

Comment: @JackDouglas It is similar to style=9 of CONVERT command. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=fa1966bf9efdd5093f56f12cbc5c9886

Comment: "And some short-key to execute instead of click on RUN button." 'r' now has [the "accesskey" attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey) so you can press it with ALT+r (or whatever — it depends on your browser and platform). Unfortunately it doesn't work while editing a textarea — you need to lose the focus first. in practice that means press TAB then hit ALT+r which works OK.

Comment: Ok @JackDouglas Thanks.

Comment: I've used Ace for syntax highlighting — can you let me know if you like it? Not sure whether to keep the line numbering or not.

Comment: @JackDouglas it's fantastic! good job. Line numbering is useful if the error message may report the line causing the error.

Comment: Good point about line numbering, it's useful here: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e2005de7d7564585ce460df5d99fc6b2

Comment: Could you tell me why [this](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b3e0f68437e7abe542a63c82b967cf77) is failing? The SQL couldn't be simpler - I just get 'invalid character' for some reason? I thought it might have been a copy and paste artefact, but not so - I typed it in manually. Puzzling!

Comment: @Vérace try it on this way: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b4af1df6b71cb8c2602e5903c83820a

Comment: Is that not a bug? I mean, to have to individually put in each record?

Comment: @Vérace I think so (for Oracle), but you should ask to [Jack Douglas](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1396/jack-douglas)

Comment: @Vérace It's difficult to make Oracle work the way some other DBs work in this scenario, because the Oracle driver doesn't do the work for me, meaning I would have to parse the SQL (something I am very keen to avoid doing). There are workarounds though, such as this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=903b08667dfeed44c8a7cca73c02dbc3

Comment: also you can click on the 'split' link to spilt a field on the default delimiter, which is a shortcut to this quickly: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b4af1df6b71cb8c2602e5903c83820a

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll take another tour - I've been using a rival site with a name not too different from yours :-) I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 9):

The only thing I need is the `Text To DDL` function from `sqlfiddle`:

[image]

Of course I can create the DDL in sqlfiddle and copy to dbfiddle. But would be nice having that function included.

Comment: that does look useful. do you know of any PHP or javascript libraries that do this sort of thing so I don't have to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Sorry I dont. But maybe you can ask @jakefeasel the sqlfiddle developer.

Comment: that gave me an idea :) — https://github.com/jackdouglas/DDLBuilder

Comment: Great. Cant wait to see it working :)

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

A few comments after superficial testing:

#### 0.

**Thank you** for the site. It's generally great!

#### 1.

Are you ok with links posted on other SO sites or ***anywhere* in the web**? Example on SO, where I just updated an existing answer with it:

- [Best way to check for “empty or null value”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)

Not sure how you would stop people from doing that, but you can stop me.

#### 2.

I have used the generic text "SQL Fiddle" to link to (mostly) sqlfiddle.com in the past. Do you think it's appropriate to use the same **text for links** to your site or do you prefer "dbfiddle" like you have it in the markup. Maybe more useful for the general public, to see where the link is going right away?

#### 3.

There might be an option to **remove** an additional SQL window (except for the first one). Currently we can only add more, but there is no way back. The Plus <kbd>+</kbd> might flip to <kbd>-</kbd>. 
Also there might be a <kbd>clear</kbd> per SQL window (additionally), not just for the whole page.

#### 4.

I like the spartan, **no-nonsense** design.

- Result fields might have a *tiny* bit more spacing. That's what I see in Firefox 51.0.1:

[image: dbfiddle results]

#### 5.

I like that we can have **any number of queries** with results.

- It might be useful to have an option to (re-)execute only one of them. i.e. a button like <kbd>run this</kbd> below each SQL window in addition to the general <kbd>run</kbd> at the end. Might require more webdesign smarts to update only the selected section (I am no expert with this.).

  While the next SQL window *can* depend on results from the previous one, that does not have to be the case (like in my example above).

  Alternatively (additionally), <kbd>run so far</kbd> could be useful.

#### 6.

I like that we have Postgres **versions** 9.4, 9.5 and 9.6 at our disposal. SQL Fiddle didn't keep up.

#### 7.

I like the **markdown** feature, which produces this (example from link above):

```
-- empty string equals any string of spaces when cast to char(n)
SELECT ''::char(5) = ''::char(5)     AS eq1
      ,''::char(5) = '  '::char(5)   AS eq2
      ,''::char(5) = '    '::char(5) AS eq3;

/*
|eq1|eq2|eq3|
|:--|:--|:--|
|t  |t  |t  |
*/
```

- What do you (or others) think about this alternative format for *results*?

> ```
> eq1 | eq2 | eq3
> ----+-----+----
> t   | t   | t
> ```

Less noise, more spacing. It's the default format in psql, with "quoted code" markdown. (Meta has no syntax highlighting, effects are better viewed on the main site.)

#### 8.

On-site **disclosure** / statements on site owner, intended use, license, update policy, expected lifetime, public visibility, privacy?

I know, it's still beta. Just mentioning it.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement Erwin — If you find dbfiddle useful then I must be getting something right. ① anywhere in the web is fine :) ② I'd prefer "dbfiddle" — though you could use the generic "fiddle". "SQL Fiddle" is (It think) Jake's trademark so should probably only be used for his site. ④ you mean the output tables or something else? A screengrab might help with this. ⑤ iiuc that won't be possible — the whole script is run as a unit and in general a SELECT is going to depend on the `INSERT` before it. There is a keyboard shortcut for the "run" button though. …

Comment: ⑦ I like your alternative format, and the markdown could be adjusted to look a bit more like that, but while there is [still some hope](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/966/1396) that we will eventually get markdown tables on dba.se, I think it would be good to use valid markdown. ⑧ yes to all of that, and also all the source code is going up on GitHub at some point. Top of my todo list is getting some more backends added (SQL Server 2014, 2012, MySQL whatever), but the rest isn't too far down…

Comment: @JackDouglas: I updated  ④ & ⑤, and added the missing ③.

Comment: I wondered about ③ :) definitely a good suggestion, I've been lazy so far because there is a secret way to get rid of fields: just leave them blank. Then they are removed when you press "run" — hardly intuitive though. ④ I've increased the left and right padding by 1px, and made the table borders grey instead of black, have I gone far enough with the padding do you think? ⑤ OK I get what you mean — but at the moment I'm unsure if that would be worth the extra complexity.

Comment: ④ works great for me now. Generally: all just ideas. The site is already a win. Most importantly, it works, and pretty quickly, too, so far.

Comment: ③ I've added 'clear' and 'remove' links to each field, does that seem like a good solution?

Comment: Awesome. A flipped button `[-]` might be ambiguous as to which field is removed. Your implementation avoids the problem.

Comment: ⑦ I've tweaked the markdown output to add spaces left and right — as per the Markdown Extra spec: https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table. By default it now only adds leading and trailing pipes for 1-column tables. I think the extra spacing is much nicer, but I'm not sure whether removing the pipes is an improvement, can you let me know your opinion? http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ea036653d8913c51e3b7441647c0d1c6#

Comment: @JackDouglas: I like both (more spacing, less unnecessary pipes) better than before. But I like the psql style still better, yet.

Comment: I'm glad you think that's an improvement — it now exactly matches the [SO documentation table markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so I think I'd better stick with it. Several people have asked about the comments — the purpose is purely so the tables don't get syntax highlighting. I could get a similar effect with `<!-- language: none -->` and `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` before/after the result but not without splitting the code block. What do you think is best?

Comment: tangentially related to ⑧, the PHP source for the postgres backends is now up on GitHub: https://github.com/jackdouglas/dbfiddle/blob/master/backend/postgres.php

Answer (score 7):

Excellent work, but I don't care much for the logo.  I'm not an artist, but here's a stab at something reminiscent of what you have.  If you don't like it, that's fine, but please find something else.

[image: dbfiddle]

[image: db<>fiddle]

Comment: Thanks very much Leigh — I'd been thinking about changing the logo to <> (as in "db<>fiddle"), but maybe this instead.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it.  What are you trying to say with db<>fiddle?  "Database not equal Fiddle" or something like "Don't fiddle with the database"?  Or is it just a symbol to separate db from fiddle?

Comment: "is it just a symbol to separate db from fiddle" yes, it's just a database-related symbol to separate db from fiddle. Also a (subtle?) joke about programmers v DBAs.

Comment: Then maybe you just want a stylized <>.  I have one, but the image upload tool doesn't seem to accept it right now.

Comment: That's probably due to the Amazon S3 outage: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/03/01/aws_s3_outage/

Comment: @JackDouglas Indeed, works now.

Comment: thanks for that too :)

Answer (score 5):

I tried the [Msft SQL Server vNext](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-vnext-including-Linux) option by copying this [SQL  Statements to create tables and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752112/) into the first field and a [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753959/819887) into the second field. You can [see the result in my dbafiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=aa8b602c889480dd702f64e09b892818).

It it unclear to me what i would have to do next, to see a result?
Some error message or some indication that the tables are created would be helpfull.

#### Update after comment that it runs now

The html structure is currently this sequence of html tags `<input><textarea /><textarea />`. It seems that the first textarea is used for the user to input data and the second is used to output a result for instance a  `✓`.

- It would be helpful to see the result next to each first textarea as either a statement (tables created) or a preview of the table strcuture (see example below). In my dbfiddle above only that the second group of (`<input><texta /><texta />`)  had an output
- I noticed that the output of my [first dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=aa8b602c889480dd702f64e09b892818) was a little off (to many white space). So I [forked the above dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=60626cdc751e9ff41aaa5f819a51877d) to confirm that the cause was the `RoomName [nchar](120)` inside  `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms]...` This made me aware that a fork button and a field to comment what was changed in the fork
  could be useful. Linking the forked fiddles could be useful as well. Another option would be to stripe (remove whitespace) of the output columns (although this might be undesired in some cases).

**Example:** Add a table definition output for each `create table`-statement next to the matching textarea field like this.

```
| column name | type        |
|-------------+-------------|
| id          | PRIMARY KEY |
| start_time  | TIMESTAMP   |
| name        | VARCHAR     |
|-------------+-------------|
```

Comment: I don't know why, but if you separate the INSERT statements from the CREATE TABLE statements things look more healthy: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=f46e62b13aa434cfff9c20ce26d4daf1

Comment: It seems `execute(@PivotBase)` is still ignored. Was my feedback [usefull](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?

Comment: Yes, useful feedback, thanks! what should `execute(@PivotBase)` return? My SQL Server knowledge is somewhat limited :)

Comment: `@PivotBase` contains an sql statement and [execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms188332.aspx) is used to  executes this sql statement.

Comment: I needed to widen the permissions — it runs now, thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to suggest a preview for each table created next to the matching textarea field.

Comment: "…either a statement (tables created) or…" in this case I prefer the former — we do need to show the 'table created' (or 'x rows inserted' or whatever) notice. That's next on my list after SQL Server 2016

Comment: re forking, every press of the 'run' button creates a fork, but as you say, there is no way of linking forks to the previous fiddle. I'm not sure that's something I'd be looking to add as it probably belongs in the write-up (blog or post on dba.se or whatever)

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks for making this tool! I tried to break the site. Hopefully some of this is useful feedback.

**1.**

Any chance of getting Oracle 12c? 11g is pretty old at this point although I think Oracle recently extended support for it.

**2.**

It looks like SQL Server 2014 is pretty close to RTM. If possible can you patch it, at least to SP2?

Testing on SQL Server 2016:

**3.**

Can we get a bit more info in the erorr messages? Here's what I get in SSMS for the following query:

```
SELECT 1 / 0
```

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Divide by zero error encountered.

Here is what I get on the site:

> Line 1: Divide by zero error encountered.

The following queries all return the "22P02ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json DETAIL: The input string ended unexpectedly. CONTEXT: JSON data, line 1:" error message:

**5.**

Any query that selects a `VARBINARY` value such as this one:

```
SELECT CAST('A' AS VARBINARY(1));
```

**6.**

This code takes a really long time to execute before failing (I would expect a timeout but if it generates too much data before doing so that's fine):

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
WHILE @i < 100
    SELECT REPLICATE('Z', 8000);
```

**7.**

```
use tempdb;
```

**8.**

```
use msdb;
```

**9.**

```
use master;
```

**10.**

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE('Z', 8001);

SELECT 
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, 
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str,
@str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str, @str;
```

**11.**

Is there an easy way to make this one display more than just seconds? It is precise to more than just seconds (as opposed to `GETDATE()`):

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME();
```

Comment: 1) Unless Oracle or someone else sponsors us, we are limited to XE, so we'll have to wait. There isn't a guarantee there will be an XE release, but if there is, it'll *probably* be this year, based on this sort of logic:  https://oracle-base.com/blog/2016/01/07/oracle-xe-12c/

Comment: 2) Thanks for pointing that out, I've patched it up to SP2: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=06073f8adae8d59fb89c8a415d4b398f

Comment: 3) Fixed: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d73e7302e285d7e6bafc3e0f73134c88

Comment: 4) I think the literal is varchar(8000) so is truncated before the cast to varchar(max). See http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=fc24eeb41cc5e16b98cf5dd3465aa834 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18491/1396

Comment: 5) I've made dbfiddle return the hex representation like SSMS: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d0bcfe0b378e8eff5e3ac208ed59c6d6

Comment: 6) "a really long time"? Not surprising really as it's an infinite loop :P (or is that your point?). When I add `SET @i = @i + 1;` I only get one result back which I found surprising, is that right? http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=07c993daa2e791104fdd67d82163ddc4

Comment: 7,8,9) I have fixed this, but am wondering if we should be using tempdb instead of creating a new database for each session?

Comment: 10) That's mean but I fixed it anyway :p

Comment: @JackDouglas Clarified in the question. Here's an example of the loop working: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b3a27db6b7c858609f3ce8853eee1114

Comment: I could add a timeout, but some fiddles legitimately take a while to execute. Not sure which is best

Comment: Regarding Oracle, you could try and reach out to Jeff http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/271/thatjeffsmith - though given the availability of Oracle Live SQL I'm not sure that they'd be up for it https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html

Comment: 11) I have no idea how to do this on Windows — vNext on Linux shows all the precision by default: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=c3fa9656d0448894c08671d774567678 (it seems to be milliseconds for GETDATE()). I have asked [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43017648/6854914)!

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Oracle  - `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` does not print anything and `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` is not working. [image]

It would be really useful to test PL/SQL programs. Is there any other way to see this output, other than creating a function and seeing output from a select?

Comment: I've been meaning to add this for a while, thanks for prompting me. How about like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=43277f27527dab8eab96de86823a1ecb

Comment: @JackDouglas : Wow!  You fixed it so quick.. Thanks a lot. That greatly helps.

Comment: glad to help — please consider following the oracle tags on dba.se I'm sure you could answer some of the questions here!

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Is there a chance we get Oracle 18c version?

[Oracle Database 18c XE now available!](https://blogs.oracle.com/oracle-database/oracle-database-18c-xe-now-available)

Comment: I've already downloaded it and hope to have it installed in the next few days :)

Comment: it's looks like it's working, so please give it a whirl: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d9c0851aaf493d9b4b417d1285d6ed4b

Comment: @JackDouglas Wow, it is marvelous! Thank you so much.  Now I could provide more demos on SO :)

Comment: @JackDouglas Polymorphic Table Function [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2a52baf82bb5a842947d14d3086d5dc4) This is  magnificent 

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Extensions / additional modules for Postgres

Besides `plpgsql` (installed by default) I currently see these additional modules on your site for PostgreSQL 11:

```
select * from pg_extension;

btree_gin
btree_gist
pageinspect
pg_trgm
postgis
postgis_topology
tablefunc
```

I repeatedly found myself wishing for some more. Most importantly:

```
intarray
hstore
tsm_system_rows
unaccent
```

All of them included in the `contrib` module of the main distribution. See: [**"Appendix F. Additional Supplied Modules"**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib.html)

`intarray`, `hstore` and `unaccent` are *essentials*, and `tsm_system_rows` is tiny and convenient.
(`dblink` is also common and useful, but may be to powerful for your site. So I did not include it in the wishlist.)

Would you think it's possible to install those?

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks for the suggestions. We've added the extensions on your wishlist to the Postgres 11 server: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8ebb8fd5b0168049c36e926f224777ff

Comment: @james: thanks a lot! i'll have a look as soon as the flu goes away.

Answer (score 3):

**Small Screens Hide Vital Controls** (eg "Run")

[image]

The images above are from a Samsung S5 using Chrome, not the largest phone screen, but also not the smallest. In landscape mode one can "just" access the Run button, but this is not possible in portrait orientation at all. While I accept that writing SQL on a phone is tedious in the extreme (well I find it is) many people do read Q/A information on such screens.

**"Split" is not an intuitive feature:**

It took me a few attempts to understand what "Split" does (divides a block of DDL/DML/SQL into individual parts on screen). This is unique to your user interface as far I can tell and certainly not a normal part of SQL. It also appears to be essential to your UI.

I didn't find this initiative at all. Personally it seems of equal importance - **and a prerequisite** - to "Run" so why isn't it just embedded into the run logic? (and/or placed to the left of run in the top menu?)

**Finding the URL**

It took me a little while to realize that I needed to use *Markdown* to locate a URL which would allow me to return to the fiddle.

**Removing the 9 unwanted "boxes" to produce "My Fiddle"**

If I open https://dbfiddle.uk by default you display multiple "splits" which are aimed at helping "me-the-dumb-user" to understand how it works. Perhaps I'm wrong, but if I want a markdown output that is exclusively related to my own fiddle, I first need to remove these "help splits". That's 9 or so remove clicks to reach a "clean start".

While help is useful for the first-time user, it's tedious for an experienced user. Why not just provide a Help link in the toolbar which displays "help"? The default screen would in that case be almost blank and ready for a new fiddle to be created with no need to hit remove multiple times.

**Off-topic content**

While faith may be an important topic to some, does it really warrant promotion from a technical help site?

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for providing an a place for sql related fiddles. Perhaps you might also consider DB2 amongst your db list? (it works on Debian it seems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DB2_Express-C)

Comment: Mmmm just found that in the top menu I can "Clear" all the unwanted "splits" with a single click which is good. I would still prefer to work the other way, have the default screen "Clear" and add "Help" if requested.

Comment: re "While faith may be an important topic to some, does it really warrant promotion from a technical help site?", see my comment here: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/a-new-fiddle-for-dba-se#comment5569_2686

Comment: re "Perhaps you might also consider DB2 amongst your db list?", with a lot of help from [@mustaccio](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio), I've finally got this working: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1

Comment: Fantastic!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Not sure if it is correct place to put bug report. But let's give a try:

When I run(SQL Server 2012-2017) I can't see any result set.

```
SELECT i, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM tab
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY ALL i;  -- ALL is deprecated feature
```

Output:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

[image]

Temporary workaround:

```
-- workaround materializng to table
SELECT i, COUNT(*) cnt
INTO tab2
FROM tab
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY ALL i;

SELECT * FROM tab2;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=bd56a484c034316e0c6726a344722ad6)**

Comment: Thanks for spotting this — I think it is now fixed. Please let me know if you find any cases where results with informational messages don't look right.

Comment: @JackDouglas Thanks for quick response. I love that site. Is there opportunity to ugrade SQLite up to 3.25.0 when it will be GA? Many new things were added.

Comment: I know it's not what you asked for, but I have added [3.16](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16). My current plan is to add whatever versions come packaged with each release of Debian (so I get security updates easily), so as long as 3.25 is released by Jan 2019 it'll appear with Buster's release later in 2019.

Comment: @JackDouglas Thanks for adding upgraded version plus info. For all available  free SQL playgrounds(db-fiddle.com/rextester.com/sqlfiddle.com) your version is truly the best. I am huge fan of showing actual working code rather than query/description only. Many times I had to prove that SQL can do things that others thought were virtually unreachable.  Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks very much for the kind words, and the encouragement to keep working on improving and updating the site. Please do feel free to post your suggestions here, and you may like to know I'm currently working on a [side-by-side compare](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&rdbms2=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=06073f8adae8d59fb89c8a415d4b398f) feature. You currently need to run the code against both databases individually then edit the url manually to get the result but there will eventually be a UI to do this :)

Comment: I already like this side-by-side feature and looking forward for release :)

Comment: @JackDouglas BTW Could you provide some statistics? Something like DB version - number of scripts created for last year. I am really curious which RDBMS is most popular.

Comment: You can probably get the info you are curious about from the 'secret' stats tables on the Postgres 9.6 database: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4f669cbc9224c5311b149593c6317d61

Comment: @JackDouglas SEDE(Stack Exchange Data Explorer) for DBFiddle.uk :) Nice

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I created a three-batch script on SQL Server 2017 (Windows):

#### Batch 1

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;

CREATE TABLE dbo.T (n integer NULL);
```

#### Batch 2

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg ON dbo.T
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #i FROM Inserted
    CREATE INDEX i ON #i (n);
END;
```

#### Batch 3

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;

INSERT dbo.T (n) VALUES (1);

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
```

This produces no output at all when <kbd>run</kbd> is clicked (I expected an error about snapshot isolation not being enabled). There is no indication that db<>fiddle has tried to execute the script at all.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please enable snapshot isolation for db<>fiddle:

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I think the bug might be a recent regression — and I think it is now fixed: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=30a687fb577c50b20204c30997db6262

Comment: I've enabled snaphot isolation on 2017 linux only because running the same script still gives a (different) error there: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=30a687fb577c50b20204c30997db6262. If you tell me that new error is expected, I'll enable it on the others too tomorrow.

Comment: That error is expected. It was the point of the demo actually.

Comment: @JackDouglas The only remaining issue is that the error message is quite long and there doesn't seem to be a way to see all of it.

Comment: Thanks, I've applied ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION to all the other versions and fixed the error message truncation :)

Answer (score 3):

Any chance you could do some user agent sniffing and completely ditch the fancy code boxes in favour of just plain old text boxes if the user is using a cellphone?

Or even simpler to implement and probably better; just a toggling link/button switcher that flips between "use fancy editor/use basic text box editor" so I can flip the mode myself?

I can't get copy or paste to work at all on an iPhone (to be fair, I haven't tested Android) with the fancy text boxes on dB<>fiddle, which kinda makes the entire site unusable for all but the simplest queries as I'd have to literally type some OP's entire query in manually off of SO etc

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks Caius, I wasn't aware cut/paste doesn't work on iPhone. I'm on holiday right now, but will take a look in a couple of weeks and think about what's best to do to improve that.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Here is an advanced attempt, trying to create and use a function:

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0c843d449e3fb7b22975c57b3594a79b

> ```
> 42883ERROR:  function f_tmp_groups() does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT * FROM  f_tmp_groups();
>                        ^
> ```

Not sure why this happens. A simple SQL function works:

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=af6b4ee3972343aaeeed4a197b5407e7

And a basic set-returning plpgsql function works, too:

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=28aae0139d521a01c26e748234fe178a

After separating `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, the first example works:

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a64f32b548c342189762e746c16a0eaa

I am confused at this point.

Aside: format of error msg ...

Comment: The first field had two statements in it, this works: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a1c3edee223c0a11660e08b73370627f — obviously the error messages are a big fail at the moment!

Comment: @JackDouglas:That's what I found, too (last link). So it's strictly 1 statement per SQL window?

Comment: sorry — I obviously didn't read right to the end. Yes, it's currently 1 statement per field — and I thought it had to be that (without me parsing the SQL). Oracle is definitely one statement per field, and SQL Server allow multiple (it's one batch per field), I assumed pg would be the same as Oracle, but…

Comment: …looking at the api docs I may have misunderstood that and might be able to change it so you can have multiple statements/results per field — I'll look into it!

Comment: 1 statement per field is fine with me. Just didn't know, yet. (Avoids complications.) Not sure how you implemented the execution. You probably only get the results of the last statement.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I've no way of enforcing 1 statement per field so I've changed the backend to handle multiple statements — it's a bit quirky though — only the *first* result set is returned (and I can't change that), so I expect that users will typically stick to one statement per field, but the important thing is that it now behaves as sane as it can and gives more sensible messages. Your original link now works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome work!

Looks like it would be handy for some of the answers I've been posting to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/, and what would be super helpful would be to have a *byte counter* somewhere underneath each code box, since most of the contests are scored by size.

Answer (score 2):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

I'll put this in as an "answer" and maybe consolidate my "bugreports" here.

I was answering [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206317/update-values-in-one-table-from-data-in-another/206343#206343), so I used your tool to construct the fiddle. It's a question about SQLite.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=6ab2d90c3517774c3b18e78ea80fabde) is the fiddle that answered the first part of the question - an `UPDATE`.

To answer part two, I tried [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=9c865677380e0dca90c2b205063c5b53). As you can see, it fails. I'm quite persistent, so I tried db-fiddle (your arch-rival? :-) ) [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qixreVSBwTArbUSa7VbVJX/0) and it works nicely.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you need 'BEGIN;' (or 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;')  not 'BEGIN' for SQLite (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_transactions.htm) this seems to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=d1a97b5febe547839a3f02ab94becc7a

Comment: and I notice you are actually using 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;' on (the other) db-fiddle

Comment: Fraid not :-) Your transaction fails silently - I did try both options! At the bottom, SELECT * FROM master should be sell, sell, not buy, buy and there's no sign of SELECT * FROM scheduled. Also, the db-fiddle works with both BEGIN and BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Comment: ah, OK, I will look into that!

Comment: The SQLlite driver doesn't allow multiple statements in each block, even if they are a single transaction, if you split them out does this do what you'd expect https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=925d9396b7ec2e2b75827d8e382a690a?  I think this fiddle shows a transaction working as expected: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=049a9f1746098ebabd02132f632fcb60

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

No `CREATE TYPE` privilege  under Oracle. It would have been greatly helpful if included, especially to test/ demonstrate queries and PL/SQL code containing collections of records and `TABLE` functions.

[image]

Comment: "It would have been greatly helpful if included, especially to test/ demonstrate queries and PL/SQL code containing collections of records and TABLE functions" very true, fixed! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f4bc9967a4efbde2320a3f74edcc9728

Answer (score 2):

Bug: If you [remove] all sections, then you get just the separator line, and no way to get an empty section. Clicking [+] just gives more separators.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Oracle collection and `COLLECT` is not showing any result.

Sample scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(NR NVARCHAR2(100), GRD NVARCHAR2(100), DT DATE);

INSERT INTO tab(NR, GRD, DT)
SELECT '00000000000000000001' AS NR,N'06' AS GRD,DATE '2013-01-01' AS DT 
FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '00000000000000000001',N'06',DATE '2013-01-01'  FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '00000000000000000001',N'21',DATE '2013-01-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '00000000000000000002',N'06',DATE '2013-01-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '00000000000000000002',N'21',DATE '2013-01-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '00000000000000000004',N'01',DATE '2013-03-31' FROM dual;

CREATE TYPE tbl_array AS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(4000);
```

And query:

```
select nr, CAST(collect(grd) AS tbl_array) grds
from tab
group by nr;
```

Should return:

```
┌──────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┬
│          NR          │              GRDS              │ 
├──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ 00000000000000000001 │ HR.TBL_ARRAY('06', '21', '06') │ 
│ 00000000000000000002 │ HR.TBL_ARRAY('06', '21')       │ 
│ 00000000000000000004 │ HR.TBL_ARRAY('01')             │ 
└──────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┴
```

But there is no result at all.

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17585a1f6b85691089e6c131f843ded7)**

[image]

Note: Similiar scenario with PostgreSQL is working fine.

[DBFiddle Demo - PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=53367d67d264b3e36bcb8a8e862a428e)

Comment: I've spent a while trawling through the PHP OCI docs and I can't see how to get the text representation of the array type (or indeed any representation). The Oracle backend is processing correctly as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9262cacd3eb0859522f9d9f9fc372353, but [oci_fetch_all](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php) returns an empty result of type "VARCHAR2Array".

Comment: @JackDouglas Hmm, that is sad. Could you at least return something like `NR - GRDS` and second row `00000000000000000001 - (user defined type)` and so on. I mean that I would rather get 3 rows with some indicator on `GRDS`  than 0 rows.

Comment: It doesn't look like I can get anything back from the PECL OCI driver at all — even when multiple rows should be returned, if a single row has a collection, the result set I get from the driver is empty. I may have better luck with a different driver but options are limited and that would likely break more than it fixes. dbfiddle doesn't parse the sql you enter, but you can work around the issue with `dump` if you just want to see something: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=12bd47a78b18ec1ac86885c531b67d17

Comment: @JackDouglas Yes, dump will do the work

Answer (score 2):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

This is just question/minor bug?
When do we get rows count?

For example **[DBFiddle Demo - PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=67e589fc21a355844639705507f495ab)** and **[DBFiddle Demo - SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c2c0bef7602b778d1cdbf67eb51eea6)**

[image]

The only difference is that I commented `WHERE` clause.

Comment: row counts kick in at >5 rows, and extra rows hidden behind an ellipsis for >10 rows (you have to click the ellipsis twice for >100 and 3 times for >1000 etc): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1cf1716d03740295c0d8d157c59ce234

Comment: @JackDouglas Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When I try to run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dual
GROUP BY ()
```

It works on [Oracle 11g](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=21dce521aa1be6ca4ff9a50e5f585f13) but fails on Oracle 18c:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for the inconvenience — the back-end instance had crashed with an ORA-00822, but the real problem is that I neglected to add the Oracle 18 backend to our monitoring system so I wasn't notified about the crash. That's now rectified, and I may later add more memory to the instance if the crash re-occurs.

Comment: @JackDouglas Could you check if Oracle18c and MySQL 8.0 are up? I am getting `Run failed` messages for any query?

Comment: both needed restarting, should be OK now…

Comment: @JackDouglas Looks ok. Thank you once again.

Comment: @JackDouglas Hi Jack, it looks like Oracle18c is down again. Simple`SELECT 1 FROM dual` - "Run failed"

Comment: sorry about that — we haven't worked out why the instance keeps stopping. It's back up now

Comment: although Oracle still crashes every now and again, we have a script running every minute to bring it back up — this seems to be working ok for now!

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

this morning I tried to use dbfiddle.uk with PostgreSQL 11.

Extremely simple sample SQL:

CREATE TABLE test (bill INTEGER, fred TEXT);

and then:

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'sdfs'), (2, 'vcxf'), (3, 'tyiro');

followed by:

SELECT * FROM test;

Result in PostgreSQL 10 (as expected):

```
bill    fred
   1    sdfs
   2    vcxf
   3    tyiro
```

But PostgreSQL 11 fails to do anything - not even the ticks for correctly creating the table and inserting the data.

The fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=adb061337d239d12ee5bc5a15efdc969). Just as an aside, it works fine for all versions of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, Erwin alerted me to this in [a comment](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/a-new-fiddle-for-dba-se?noredirect=1#comment5967_2686) and I think it is fixed. I need to find a way of restricting rogue fiddles from using up all available disk space…

Comment: Yes - it's fixed now. Wow, that took all of 17 minutes from bug report to fix. If only my bug reports to suppliers were sorted so quickly! :-)

Comment: well it was a bit longer than that since Erwin's comment, but thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comments/Bugs link on dbfiddle.uk directs me to here, so I suppose "answering" is the way to submit bugs:

Select MySQL 5.7 as database and try this extra simple DML command:

```
create table errorTest (id integer, issue text);
insert into errorTest (id, issue) values (1,'issue #1');
```

It is expected to work but comes up with an error message saying:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'insert into errorTest (id, issue) values (1,'issue #1')' at line
>   2

Comment: yes this is exactly the right way to submit bugs, thanks :) the MySQL PHP driver we use does not accept multiple statements per line, so you have to split them up: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f915bbccc5e87995c55f27ca618e8292

Comment: I see you [have used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54427779/6854914) — it's a bit confusing that the SQL Server driver is happy to have multiple statements per batch and MySQL is not.

Comment: actually it looks like [it is possible](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php), but when I've [asked before](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48369505#48369505) I've been told it isn't necessary. Do you think it would be helpful compared to just splitting up the fields?

Comment: `Sorry I don't understand the comments exactly, as far as I understand, you are saying it is a fault of PHP. Driver accepts multiple statements with 65536 parameter, no? Anyway, I am not a fan of MySQL. The same query works well on db-fiddle.com and sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: I'll let you know when we get multiple batches working (using mysqli, so not as simple as passing 65536 would be unfortunately, but apparently still possible)

Comment: Hi Cetin, I've implemented this feature — please let me know if it doesn't work the way you expect. Here is your example code working: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=973f4a7bc6695b9b098fc6213fe4ce9f

Comment: Thanks for the update, it is working fine now :) I am glad, I prefer dbfiddle.uk over other sites (wish I knew hosting problem before).

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement and support — feel free to bring up anything else here, eg improvement suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

For Postgres please add the `ltree` extension :) That would be great. Sometimes there are SO questions referencing it.

Comment: I've added ltree for versions 10,11 and 12 :)

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! This is so helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Bug report: cannot create a function in MariaDB [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8b22a5a31dc3e12d8806c845df889689):

> You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

though for MySQL I can.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about this, it's all working now.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks for your site.

I have two requests:

1. Improvement: current Firebird is 3.0.1, the current latest is 3.0.4. Would it be possible to upgrade?
2. Bug: The result set uses the 'original column name' instead of the alias. The 'original column name' isn't always present. Depending on how the query is constructed it is 'lost' in some versions of Firebird, or never existed in the first place (eg with literals in the select clause), and for example function calls will use the function as the original column name.

   For an example see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=ece84ac17427cc52a1d6ffccc663e17e). The first select should have column heading `SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID, ENTRY_TIME, DURATION`, but has `(empty), (empty), DATEDIFF`. The second select should have `SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID, ENTRY_TIME, DURATION`, but has `SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID, ENTRY_TIME, DATEDIFF`.

   [image]

   In the low-level Firebird API this is the difference between using `isc_info_sql_field` (original column name) or `isc_info_sql_alias` (alias).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've switched from Debian Stretch to Buster which has 3.0.5 packaged, and fixed the alias/name bug.

Comment: @JackDouglas Thanks! Be aware that - although pretty stable - 3.0.5 is not yet released.

Comment: I'm not sure why the Debian team decided to use 3.0.5 before release, but it might be related to this bug: https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-11509. I'm doubly grateful for this bug report as the security vulnerability slipped under my radar and this kind of thing is potentially very nasty for db<>fiddle.

Comment: @JackDouglas Possibly, yes. In Firebird 4 UDF support will be disabled by default and it has been deprecated (the replacement feature, UDR (User-Defined Routines), has mitigations for this AFAIK). You can disable it in any firebird version by setting `UdfAccess = None` in `firebird.conf`.

Comment: Thanks — that's useful to know.

Comment: hopefully External Tables were disabled too in conf-file? Or at least are directed to special disk volume that can be safely overflowed without affecting rest of the service.

Comment: @Arioch'The The `ExternalFileAccess`  setting defaults to `None` so it is disallowed by default, contrary to `UdfAccess` which defaults to `Restrict UDF` which means it points to the `UDF` directory of the Firebird install by default.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel in vanilla sources tarball - perhaps. But what about specific Linux distro binary repo? for such a thing as vastly promoted WWW site - security is to be checked not implied I guess

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The height of the scroll container is too low. I strips of some pixels from the lowest line, making commas and other delimiters quite unreadable:

[image: lower pixels of the line are hidden, commas show as dots, semicolons and colons are indistinguishable]

The height seems to be computed explicitly somewhere and set as an inline style. Using `em` here works better for me, or just add some margin please.

Comment: Thanks for prompting me to fix this, it was an annoying niggle.

Comment: Whoa thanks, that was quick!

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There are problems in the display of space / empty string / NULL value:

```
 VALUES
  (1, 'foo')
, (2, '')
, (3, NULL)
, (4, '   ')
, (5, '|   |');

/*
column1 | column2
------: | :------
      1 | foo    
      2 |        
      3 |        
      4 |        
      5 | |   |  
*/

VALUES
  ('foo')
, ('')
, (NULL)
, ('   ')
, ('|   |');

/*
| column1 |
| :------ |
| foo     |
|         |
|         |
|         |
| |   |   |
*/
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f98fb5ac5e9278c170fcbbcc5686e2df)*

In the online display:

- Note the collapsed row 2 for the empty string in the second SQL field - in the fiddle, not here.

In the markup:

- *Some* way to distinguish rows 2, 3 and 4 would be useful.

---

I sharpened the demo to include single quotes and `<tag>`):

```
VALUES
  ('<tag>')
, (NULL)
, ('')      -- empty string
, ('''''')  -- actual single quotes
, ('   ');  -- spaces

/*
| column1 |
| :------ |
| <tag>   |
|         |
|         |
| ''      |
|         |
*/
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0f2ed2d8873a1eb6e62db849e3a45d61)*

***Maybe*** rendering with a `<pre>` block would be an improvement? Would also take care of [the comments you mentioned](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/a-new-fiddle-for-dba-se/2708?noredirect=1#comment4919_2708).

```
| column1 |
| :------ |
| <tag>   |
| null    |
| ''      |
| ''      |
|         |
```

You'd have to escape `<`. I used `&lt;` above ...

Included your italic null, added italic single quotes for empty string. May be hard to distinguish from literal single quotes. But still an improvement, because the distinction between empty string and space is more important because it's a more common problem.

All spaces remain to be solved ... Some corner cases are hard to solve. Most clients have a hard time to get it right.

The only change I am *convinced* is good is the italic null. The rest is just ideas ...

See this related meta-post:

- [Syntax highlighting: <!-​- language: lang-none --> does not seem to work for block quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265948/syntax-highlighting-language-lang-none-does-not-seem-to-work-for-blo)

Comment: I can put an italic `*null*` in row 3 for the markdown too, but I can't think of a good way of distinguishing rows 2 and 4, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @JackDouglas: Italic null sounds like a good idea. I added some more above.

Comment: I found this was much harder than I anticipated due to the way SE handles code blocks and syntax highlighting. The only solutions I found that retained syntax highlighting also separated the SQL and result table into two block visually which I think isn't good. In the end, all I've done is add a plain 'null' for nulls in the markdown (no way of disambiguating the text "null"), and added a &nbsp; where there is an empty string in the tabular output to prevent rows collapsing: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0f2ed2d8873a1eb6e62db849e3a45d61

Comment: @JackDouglas: I expected this to be harder than it looks ...  Separating code and results does not seem so bad to me. I often do that on purpose in my answers.

Comment: What do you think of this output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ0Xu.png

Comment: I mean just from the POV of the blockquote to separate the statement/result pairs

Comment: I think that's good.

Comment: OK, I've implemented that on a trial basis, we'll see if others agree it is an improvement. I think it is, and I'm delighted that the syntax highlighting works, there is no need for the `/* */` commenting, and we can have italic *null* in the markdown output, all at once. Thanks a lot for the input Erwin.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

First, thank you for the site, it's a very useful tool.

Recently MySQL 8.0 introduced [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table), however, it's currently not possible to use it in dbfiddle.uk.

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac47f5069f67c4af5353e7b5b3864556).

Comment: Thanks wchiquito, after a bit of digging I found there is a bug fixed in 8.0.13, which is not yet released. See [on bugs.mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90610) (last comment in particular) and [the 8.0.13 changelog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html) — If you ping me here when 8.0.13 is released I'll update the back-end!

Comment: I've upgraded to 8.0.13 and it's all working now :)

Comment: @JackDouglas: Everything working as expected. Thanks for the quick update.

Comment: @JackDouglas: It seems that MySQL 8.0 has some problem, it does not execute sentences. Thanks.

Comment: apologies it was down for a while — but now working again.

Comment: @JackDouglas: Excellent, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I really love the db<>fiddle. But sadly I am never able to edit my fiddles with my smartphone (Android, Chrome). There is a very strange behavior with text typing. It sometime overrides the original text when trying to insert something or puts the new text on wrong positions.

The cursor behavior is very strange as well or better: it is hard to handle (finding the right position, move something, ...)

It would be great to use your fiddle on mobile devices as well. Maybe you could check this because at the moment it is really not usable for me.

Comment: I haven't currently got an Android phone to test on, so I've only tested it on iPhone. We'd certainly like to get it working properly on Android, so I'll see if I can get hold of something to test it on.

Comment: Do you know a good Android emulator for OSX?

Comment: No I am sorry. I am out of Android development for a few days. Hoping someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

I got a problem with MySQL when I wanted to execute more statements in one field.

Please have a look at this working example (Postgres):
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a0fc52d4e45e4d925b428fabcdee70f5

Now I changed the DBMS into MySQL and tried the same:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0fc52d4e45e4d925b428fabcdee70f5

That wasn't working. But if I split the statement into one field each, it is working:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6166ff71140b5957794f1f6c9fb9780

Why does the multi execution work with Postgres but not with MySQL?

Comment: db<>fiddle's design philosophy is against parsing the SQL you enter at all (the one exception being the 'split batch' function, but that is really peripheral to the main working of the site). In other words, this behaviour is inherited from the database itself, or the drivers used to access the DB. There is either something about MySQL or something about the MySQL driver for PHP causing this. It may well be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13982705/6854914 but it looks like there are pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

I really like to know: When I execute multiple statements in one field (e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a0fc52d4e45e4d925b428fabcdee70f5), are they treated as one transaction or are they committed separately?

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=359d2d77699702bac5c359df0a635d2e

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Bug for MySQL-8.0

```
SELECT
  json_tb.item_id,
  json_tb.model_number,
  json_tb.quantity
FROM JSON_TABLE
(
'[{"item_id":1,"model_number":"MFJA53","quantity":4},{"item_id":2,"model_number":"HSRHJN5","quantity":null},{"item_id":3,"model_number":"FAFAF1","quantity":345}]'
, "$[*]"
COLUMNS
(
item_id int PATH "$.item_id",
model_number varchar(100) PATH "$.model_number",
quantity int PATH "$.quantity"
)
) json_tb
```

Returns:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'fiddle_SMYHCBMIQRDQGWHKBNDS'@'localhost' for table 'json_table'
```

json_table is a function more than a table (ref: [JSON_TABLE function manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table))

Comment: This was reported [earlier](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3048/1396) and we were waiting for MySQL to release a fix, but thanks for bringing it up again as it prompted me to check back and discover the release was ready. It should all be working now.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Would it be possible to show multiple outputs in one SQL field? At the moment if you have two SELECT statements only one will be shown in the results.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c17a17e3a448a08adc851b21d0bea5d2

For my Postgres answers I like to do these steps: CREATE TABLE, INSERT data and SELECT * FROM new_table to show how the origin table and its content look like. For multiple tables I have to use two section only for the SELECT part.

It's nothing critical, I know. But it would be nice candy I think!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think that's an easy thing to do with the postgres PHP driver we are using. It works fine with SQL Server: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c17a17e3a448a08adc851b21d0bea5d2. You can split the batch automatically with one of the icons inside the hamburger on the right but I'm not sure that is what you want.

Comment: btw this works now — I forgot to mention I found a bug in the driver and realised there was a workaround

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

On SO in the PostgreSQL section there are often PostGIS questions. At the moment I don't know any fiddle engine which supports this framework. So as a suggestion: Wouldn't it be great to install the PostGIS frame along with your PostgreSQL instances?

Comment: I've not done this before but it turns out it's reasonably straightforward as the same PG repo for postgres also contains PostGIS. Please try it out on pg11: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1b067022fa537fa82e5fcb0c98859d61

Comment: Great, works like charm :) Will you activate it on previous versions too?

Comment: We added it to 10 and 9.6 too — I don't think we'll add it to any of the older versions though.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I have to say it once again: **db<>fiddle is simply the best**.

---

I have a small request. Could you add traceflag 460 to startup parameters after you patch SQL Server with the newest cumulative update?

Current CU of SQL Server 2017 is CU9.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42d86ffb6571ea13e7c04875ade35d3c)**

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateLevel'),@@version;
-- CU9
```

I would like to be able to use:

[Improvement: Optional replacement for "String or binary data would be truncated" message with extended information in SQL Server 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4468101/optional-replacement-for-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)

Which was previously intended to be SQL Server 2019 feature [Truncation error message improved to include table and column names, and truncated value (CTP 2.1)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-ver15?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)

Comment: We've applied CU12 and added traceflag 460; here is a [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e3d1e4ecb83e5c24b7f833d88766996)

Comment: @JamesDouglas Once again, huge kudos for all your efforts and help.

Comment: @JamesDouglas see how this error is displayed in Firebird: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=8e3d1e4ecb83e5c24b7f833d88766996 - I mean, the error is supposed to be on two or maybe three separate lines, but it was fused into one continuous line, and without separators it is harder to read...

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Attempting to run the following two SQL Server batches on any available db<>fiddle version:

```
SET LANGUAGE Italiano;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2019.06.30', 0);
```

```
SET LANGUAGE Italiano;
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2019.06.30', 0);
```

[image: db<>fiddle screen capture]

Produces an error:

[image]

The code runs 'successfully' in SSMS producing the expected message and error for the first statement:

```
L'impostazione della lingua è stata sostituita con Italiano.
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
La conversione di un tipo di dati varchar in datetime ha generato un valore non compreso nell'intervallo dei valori consentiti.
```

The second statement does not produce an error, but does produce the informational message:

```
L'impostazione della lingua è stata sostituita con Italiano.
```

Comment: Running just the first one fails on most but shows an error on 2017: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44d00942c80f6299de4faa0775cc16a8. Do you get the same error in SSMS?

Comment: Yes the error is expected - answer updated to clarify (sorry about that)

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems there is a bug with DB-fiddle regarding detecting or reporting of Firebird errors.

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=57729b31e0a5019aea68a136638d9f50

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096187

Last query should generate an internal Firebird error (as Numeric is capped with 18 digits in FB 2/3 and 18-4*4=2 is not enough to contain the calculation result of 1875).

DB fiddle displays neither error nor query result.

Comment: This looks like a Firebird bug to me as a resultset is returned (albeit empty) rather than an error generated: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=ec07e9240a06dcba3be6cd87ca62f2fa

Comment: @JackDouglas the error IS generated, try local tools like FlameRobin or IBExpert or even console iSQL tool of the Firebird package. The resultset is not a static object, it is a vessel to be filled with data, as you fetch next rows. It is fetching the specific row that leads to overflow and error generation. You may avoid fetching all/any rows, but you still will have some rows and the resultset itself usable as meta-data. So, I see no bag on FB part there.

Comment: Imagine fetching `f1 / f2` from a table having rows like `1; 1`, `2; 2`, `3; 3`, `0; 0`, `4; 4` - obviously only fetching the 4th row will trigger the error, prior rows can be perfectly fetched! Think about Firebird as a `lazy` evaluator, which only makes actual actions (and has chance to trigger errors) when (whether) was actually asked by client to do it. Before the erratic row was fetched - there was no condition of error, thus no reason to deny creating the yet empty resultset.

Comment: ah, it looks like it is exposed as a PHP warning row by row by ibase_fetch_row, thanks.

Comment: yep, in my division by zero example you might even both display the starting part of the output and THEN display an error. It is not either-or :-)

Comment: WEIRD result: I just clicked yours then my link, and the tab with my link acted weirdly. It had "ok" mark on the #1 query and sensible result on #3 query, but "error table does not exist" on #2 and #4. Then I manually pressed "run" and it went all ok. I reloaded page, and (I suppose being cached now) it loaded ok again. But, be it because I clicked both your and mine links in almost the same time, or be it because I did not clicked my own link for hourse and it needed warming up, dunno, but initial load was the errors...

Comment: because Firebird isn't heavily used I'm making changes to the code in prod — that will explain the weird results. If bad results are cached the 'run' should clear them.

Comment: ah, ok, could be then, just did not expected so tight a race conditions :-D

Comment: I think the issue is now fixed, though I think we expected this to produce a good row and then an error but it does not: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=71ab81a3cc373d6fa6be75ddcc078f18.

Comment: OT: notice how I had to inject a "hackish" query to learn the Firebird version. Perhaps it might make sense to always report the server version somewhere at [age bottom after "run" pressed ?

Comment: This works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=8ddf7bc295981b4cfe643146ca925185 - so I guess the case is about datatypes: integer being up-lifted to the same Numeric, and then we have the same problem of too few digits left. Your site does not report data types in result sets, i'll try this locally in FB 2.1.7/IBExpert

Comment: Oh, sorry, pal, I am really really stupid with this issue! consider this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=d93111f4255c1ba8b2eef24a18e47f1b  The trouble is obvious, as all `union`-ed queries share the same result set - the datatypes are stretched for every columns according to the most needy query. In your link - the LAST one was forcing the 6-digits (before dot) wide `Numeric(18, 4*3)` - which was not enough for 60^4 albeit was enough for 60^3. Remove the last query - and the datatype falls back to `Numeric(18,3*3)` which has 9-digits and is enough for 60^4 to fit

Comment: Yeah, here goes another proof :-) - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=25ef86de4da395941f38c9cef1db3ce1

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense now. So it stops at the first error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=367dbac57d27b768234759a0b7cc0604

Answer (score 1):

Few UI notes.

1. MS IE 11 rendering is garbled (who would have thought :-D ) - the first vertical splitter is too high, and the "run" button is too narrow.

[image]

If anything, "MSIE6 compatibility mode" is not fixing it but makes a total mess :-)

2. Feature Request, can you make the vertical splitter (when it is vertical) to be user-draggable left and right? Perhaps it is to be a fiddle-global (page-global) thing, affecting all the queries at once - less flexible, but more eye-candish and simple to control. Perhaps something like this: http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/xsplitter.php

Comment: I'm not convinced it's worth the effort to support IE11 — but I will look into making the vertical splitter user-draggable, thanks for the xsplitter link!

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When working with Firebird, you cannot create a VIEW.

Error:

> unsuccessful metadata update CREATE VIEW VW_TEST failed There is no privilege for this operation

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=28424a97e1b71015573dc33f6ad12fd7)

Comment: Thanks Anton, that's fixed — but there are probably other privileges we should consider granting, please let me know if you run into any.

Comment: @JackDouglas Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Now tracked [here](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=30#a626)

---

The [19.2 release](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/cockroachdb-19dot2-release/) makes it look like integrating it might be relatively easy, would you be interested in adding CockroachDB as a supported platform?

The [`cockroach demo`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/dev/cockroach-demo.html) command ostensibly provides an ephemeral in-memory enterprise instance; and having seen it in action it appears to do what it says on the tin :)

Comment: That does look interesting. Core is free, but the 'demo' (which seems like it might be ideal) loads a temporary enterprise license — but I can't find out whether usage is restricted except for the 1 hour time limit, do you know?

Comment: @JackDouglas I've just heard back from my account rep & confirmed that this usage is within the licensing guidelines 

Answer (score 1):

Running into a display bug with SQL Server (any version) related to the ***precision*** displayed for `DATETIME2` values.

This [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=247c3f3279c21b8806b4a79eb8cb83c2) should be pretty much self-explanatory, but regardless of the precision defined, the output only shows the value up to the second.

Comment: FYI - you prompted some further discussion with this post over on [this ta.xyz thread](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=30#a576) in case you're interested

Comment: Hi John, the output still isn't perfect, but [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=19608cf0c1615455368805dab63152ee) shows things are better than before!

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFormat](https://sqlformat.org/) has an API (and code) to clean up syntax to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing the possibility to copy the table results for the SO editor. If I simply copy the table I end up with things like that:

```
user_id     check_date  day     time_in     time_out    hours   status
53  2018-07-16 00:00:00+01  Monday      08:15:17    09:38:03    25.3794444444444    present
53  2018-07-17 00:00:00+01  Tuesday                 absent
53  2018-07-18 00:00:00+01  Wednesday   06:34:13    08:05:17    1.51777777777778    present
```

The columns and values are not really aligned together. So I always have to append a manual formatting step (e.g. converting tabs into spaces):

```
user_id   check_date               day         time_in    time_out   hours              status
53        2018-07-16 00:00:00+01   Monday      08:15:17   09:38:03   25.3794444444444   present
53        2018-07-17 00:00:00+01   Tuesday                                              absent
53        2018-07-18 00:00:00+01   Wednesday   06:34:13   08:05:17   1.51777777777778   present
```

In SQLFiddle you can chose the output between (table, plaintext, markdown). Even plaintext looks much better and can be taken for copying into SO without any addional work:

```
| user_id |           check_date |       day |  time_in | time_out |                hours |  status |
|---------|----------------------|-----------|----------|----------|----------------------|---------|
|      53 | 2018-07-16T00:00:00Z | Monday    | 08:15:17 | 09:38:03 |   25.379444444444445 | present |
|      53 | 2018-07-17T00:00:00Z | Tuesday   |   (null) |   (null) |               (null) |  absent |
|      53 | 2018-07-18T00:00:00Z | Wednesday | 06:34:13 | 08:05:17 |   1.5177777777777777 | present |
```

Edit: dbfiddle markdown syntax

```
> user_id | check_date             | day       | time_in  | time_out | hours               | status 
> ------: | :--------------------- | :-------- | :------- | :------- | :------------------ | :------
>      53 | 2018-07-16 00:00:00+01 | Monday    | 08:15:17 | 09:38:03 | 25.3794444444444    | present
>      53 | 2018-07-17 00:00:00+01 | Tuesday   | <em>null</em>     | <em>null</em>     | <em>null</em>                | absent 
>      53 | 2018-07-18 00:00:00+01 | Wednesday | 06:34:13 | 08:05:17 | 1.51777777777778    | present
```

As you can see, the second row is not really aligned. Furthermore you can find the `<em>` tags and things like that.

---

Added by Jack:

> ```
> select 1, null;
> ```
>
> ```
> ?column? | ?column?
> -------: | :-------
>        1 | null
> ```

Comment: have you tried the 'markdown' link at the top?

Comment: Yes, of course. But it creates markdown syntax which is not a really good result (appending example)

Comment: The <em> tag is the only one — and it's there to distinguish between "null" (the string) and an actual null result. I guess it would be nice if the alignment took that into account, but does it really matter for SO? Also, when I paste in the markdown directly from db<>fiddle to an SO answer it doesn't look like yours: I'll edit an example into your question.

Comment: Yours is indented and missing the <pre> tags

Comment: @JackDouglas Thanks for you great tool. But I still miss the feature of a plain text output. I have different use cases where I need a good text style as in the psql console. The only fiddle engine that has it integrated is SQL Fiddle (as shown above). I really don't need markdown, just simple table lines. That's one of the last reasons when I have to use SQL Fiddle instead of your great tool. I would be really appreciated and it would really really help me a lot if you could integrate such an output option as well. SQL Fiddle also offers the 3 versions.

Comment: Is there any news on this one? Although I love your tool, but for textual representation without markdown syntax I have to use another tool which is quite frustrating. DBeaver improved its support for great text output in version 6.

Comment: still thinking about this — you can paste the markdown into SO and then copy the text output from there (just like you can copy the "added by Jack" table directly from the output above). Does that give you the kind of text output you need (albeit with an extra step)?

Comment: Hm, yes this could be a work around... But the extra step does not feel very good imho :D

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Could you make the default number of lines to something like 10 instead of 1?

Comment: I don't think that's an improvement — I prefer to see more batches on the page if they fit.

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Feature request: Firebird Query plans

The topic post features a screenshot with MS SQL query with the query plan rendered.
Firebird also has plan output feature, and it was enhanced in Firebird 3 to be more human-readable.

- Example of output: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-planoutput.html
- Mention of Firebird API to be used: https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=36639
- Buffer size needed to get new "explained plan" in Firebird sources and the routine fetching it should be 64KB (`MAX_USHORT`) for Firebird 2.5+ - see `isql.h` and `static void process_plan()` in `isql.epp` starting with https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/commit/24b7a7982cbae16b3c01629b58325b1ade37385e#diff-5a884df9c41990ebe603e73e1b9a05ba

I wonder if PHP FB library has or can be modified to have support for fetching query plan as well as resulting data.

Comment: I think this is only going to happen if Firebird exposes a 'pure sql' means of retrieving the plan. None of the other backends have any special code to achieve this.

Comment: @JackDouglas you mean like "all other backends expose plans to db<>fiddle already" or like "db<>fiddle only displays plans for those back-ends, that have SQL-level acccess to it" ?

Comment: I mean the latter — db<>fiddle has a very simple codebase, for example it does not parse SQL at all (except in the front end when splitting batches). Adding specialised code for query plans would go against that philosophy. There'd have to be a very strong reason to persuade me to do it.

Comment: An example case where I've already done something 'against my rule' is for the graphical query plan for SQL Server. However SQL Server is the most popular database on db<>fiddle and I take that into account too.

Comment: i hoped you could submit a patch updtream, to PHP itself :-D

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Feature Request: display server version. Sometimes tools like `db<>fiddle` are used to test some edgy query on different server versions, like looking for a bug in either query or server.

Usually database engines have some means to query version, but they may be not exposed to SQL or may require some in-depth knowledge.

It would be nice if after pressing "Run" button the DBMS version, as detailed as reasonable, was displayed for example in left bottom corner of the page.

In case of Firebird it can be obtained:

- brief version by `select RDB$GET_CONTEXT('SYSTEM','ENGINE_VERSION') from rdb$database`
- detailed version by asking for "version" and "implementation" with PHP function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fbird-server-info.php

Comment: Firebird's idiomatic way of showing the version is a bit odd but good enough for the rare cases when you want to draw attention to it I think.

Comment: i think it actually to be useful for every server, notice the question about MS SQL ans specific Cumulative Update, etc. And "idiomatic way" does not make differences between different builds of 3.0.5.x, which perhaps does matter for not yet released work-in-progress software

Comment: @JackDouglas I see you finally did it, though in quite a different way! What can I say - great option! I did not think of such an implementation :-D

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Now when you open new fiddle for any RDBMS - it starts not with a clean slate but with a RDBMS-specific version query. For the "end-user" of the new query the result is mostly the same. For readers of already existing fiddles it might be different, depending on the fiddle developer.

Comment: Actually that's always how it worked — but only if you go to the home page and don't press 'run'. Not 100% intuitive I admit

Comment: maybe then add button "check rdbms version" that would explicitly do it ?

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

A couple of nice-to-haves would be:

Ctrl-Enter to run the code rather than having to use the mouse?

and also, after running the code, can we be dropped at the **end** of the page? Normally, one tries stuff, progresses, then adds more - so the focus of interest is normally at the bottom of the page. It's irritating to have to scroll down each time and it would be deadly if we could be dropped to the bottom of the page.

Informix?

As I said, these are nice to haves and kudos for your amazing achievement so far - I particularly appreciate the fact that you cater for Firebird - a totally underrated and overignored system that (like PostgreSQL) is (vastly) superior to MySQL (`<rant>` how is it the most successful of the F/LOSS servers despite being the worst of them? `</rant>`...) - is the code up on GitHub or similar yet - you did mention that at one point.

Finally, could you please make one-off payments possible? I don't like the idea of recurring payments and would just like to make a (small) one-off donation for the excellent service you provide to the community.

EDIT (22/11/2019):

Hi again Jack, a few things too big to put into a comment.

- The Ctrl-Enter thing works but, as I said earlier, erratically. It seems to drop you somewhere in the middle of the page regardless of where you were last editing - which can in fact be confusing! I've noticed this behaviour on Windows, Linux and Mac Airbook.
- `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` doesn't work on [MySQL 8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31b0fa19b72d604381aa7b25ef59db1d) but does on [MySQL 5.7](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=31b0fa19b72d604381aa7b25ef59db1d)? `EXPLAIN` does work for both.
- I discovered the above issue when looking for timings for MySQL. They don't come with the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` whereas they do with PostgreSQL (gotta love it!). Would there be a way of including timings by default?
- With the Microsoft Edge browser (for the 5 people who use it! :-) ), if you try and copy and paste the results from a db<>fiddle query into the StackExchange text boxes, it looks like this (compare with the [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253864/gaps-and-islands-with-gps-breadcrumb-data/253883#253883) and the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=98a9c02fbe15ae405aff5501cdb2f3fd) it was copied in from using Chrome):

Every single column name/field becomes a new line:

```
tid_1
tid_2
loc_1
loc_2
ldt_1
ldt_2
diff
Mon
Mon
Hom
Hom
2019-10-22 10:27:40
2019-10-22 11:22:40
3300
Mon
Mon
Gas
Gas
2019-10-22 12:43:00
2019-10-22 13:43:00
3600
Mon
Mon
Hom
Hom
2019-10-22 16:43:00
2019-10-22 17:43:00
3600
Mon
Mon
Hom
Hom
2019-10-22 20:43:00
2019-10-22 20:56:00
780
```

As for Informix, I wrote to them:

> Dear Sir or Madam, I wish to use your Informix Innovator-C Edition for
>   a not-for-profit project and am wondering if the licence will permit
>   this? The site/project is one which permits users to test SQL against
>   servers to which they may not have (immediate/current) access (small
>   data volumes). I believe that such usage would be covered by the "free
>   for development, testing, and small production use." section of the
>   licence (from here: https://www.ibm.com/products/informix/editions),
>   but would just like to confirm. Should you require any further
>   information, please don't hesitate to contact me. Best regards,

and they replied:

> Thank you for contacting the IBM Service Center. I refer to your
>   e-mail received 05.11.2019
>
> You have reached the IBM UK General Enquiries.
>
> With your inquiry please contact our Support team for Informix
>   products on +44 800 013 0333. Please note this department is only
>   reachable via phone as it hasn’t got a general email address.
>
> Or visit our website on http://www-306.ibm.com/software/data/
>
> Or you can also contact our Software Team on +44 239 228 2340
>
> If we can be of any further assistance please do not hesitate to
>   contact us at ibm_crc@uk.ibm.com Any requests sent through to the
>   representative directly will not be actioned immediately.
>
> Kind Regards,
>
> Pavol

I tried ringing but got put on hold and as it's an international call for me, I didn't fancy racking up large bills. If you are UK based (?) maybe you might fancy ringing the 0800 number (free from UK AFAIK)? This isn't a big deal for me personally - I haven't used Informix in years, but it was my first RDBMS (and a good one), so there's a residue of affection but it appears to be slowly withering on the vine in any case. A quick check shows 68 questions all told with the Informix tag, slightly behind Firebird with 77.

Should you require any further information/testing, please don't hesitate to ping me. Again, I would like to thank you for your sterling efforts on behalf of the community to date.

Comment: That's great! A -1 for this post. I just wish the person who downvoted me had the decency to tell me why. I was suggesting nice-to-haves and **not demanding** anything - as it is, dbfiddle.uk is a great contribution to the community - which I **did specifically mention** in the point/question. Ah well...

Comment: Ignore the DV Verace, someone could have got the wrong end of the stick or could just be trolling — we'll never know unless they tell us. Maybe a big MySQL fan! Anyway, I think these are good suggestions and I've added CTRL-Enter to run, and done something a bit different to scroll position; rather than always scrolling to the bottom, I just save and restore the current scroll position. I think that's going to be better in most cases, but let me know what you think (and whether CTRL-Enter actually works — I've only tested Cmd+Enter on my mac!)

Comment: Thanks for your kind remarks - but the downvote was before I added the bit about Firebird/MySQL. Super-kudos for your prompt reply and implementation of the Ctrl-Enter - that works a treat. I've messed around with Windows 10, Chrome and the cursor position after `Run` appears to work erratically - haven't been able to nail down the exact conditions under which it happens and when it doesn't quite work. I'm off to the girlfriend's later so I won't be testing this evening :-) I will take a look tomorrow and try and figure out the way it's working on my setup. Can check on Linux-will report back!

Comment: re Informix, Express Edition doesn't appear to be free — is there a suitable free edition?

Comment: You probably want the Innovator-C edition https://www.ibm.com/products/informix/editions -- free for "small production".

Comment: Not sure if you're notified of every edit to answers in the thread - I've added a couple  of things to my original post - lemme know if you need anything.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I'm so excited I found dbfiddle! What a wonderful service to have at hand, thank you! I was especially floored by how it's already got CU1 applied to SQL Server 2019, or Firebird 3.0.5, both released mere days ago.
However, I'm here with a bug report, for Firebird specifically.

There's something wonky going on with [LIST()](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-list), Firebird's version of GROUP_CONCAT() in MySQL/SQLite, or STRING_AGG() in Postgresql/MS SQL Server. It's supposed to return a text string, but on dbfiddle I keep getting odd binary values.

Here's a simple [example dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=c08516f051a7687701e265fd31ee16e1):

> ```
> select list(t) from (select 'hello' as t from rdb$database union select 'world' from rdb$database);
> ```
>
> ```
> | LIST               |
> | :----------------- |
> | 0x0000000100000000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=c08516f051a7687701e265fd31ee16e1)*

On any system I have, this returns the expected 'hello,world' not 0x0000000100000000 which I honestly can't even imagine where that might be coming from. An errant UDF overriding the built-in function?

Comment: Can you repost this on our [current bug tracker](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=30#question) please? At some point we will probably move to a GitHub issue tracker but we aren't there yet…

Comment: The answer is right there in the linked documentation: "Result type: `BLOB`".